# Using External Library in Java Error: No OptionHandler is registered to handle class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, args4j

I'm working on a project which is running on console. There are three class file. Main.java, User.java Options.java. I'm using args4j to parse command line arguments.

I compile a project from the command line first time. I compiled the project with the following command:

```
javac -cp .:args4j-2.0.21.jar Main.java User.java Options.java
```

The project build successful and I typed following command to run project:

```
java -cp .:args4j-tools-2.0.21.jar Main User Options
```

I got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.kohsuke.args4j.IllegalAnnotationError: No OptionHandler is registered to handle class java.lang.Object
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:166)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.addArgument(CmdLineParser.java:110)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:38)
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:93)
at ScatterBrain.main(ScatterBrain.java:48)
```

Which command I have to type to build the project?

MyOption Class:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyOptions{


@Option(name="-r",usage="recursively run something")
private boolean recursive;

@Option(name="-str")        // no usage
private String str = "(default value)";

@Option(name="-n",usage="usage can have new lines in it\n and also it can be long")
private int num;

// receives other command line parameters than options
@Argument
private List arguments = new ArrayList();


}
```

Comment: I guess you have to provide the sources of your main class to see your parser configuration... The build seems to be ok. This is a runtime failur due to the framework does not know how to handle an Object...

Comment: Thanks I will check with another examples. Also, added above.

Comment: Sorry, the `MyOptions` is the place where the problem is...

Comment: The issue is that you're providing spurious arguments (1) not required by the `java` command ("User" and "Options"), and (2) not defined as arguments for Args4J. You only need to pass in the class name of where your `main` method lives.

Comment: Thanks for comment @dave, 
I typed that `java -cp .:args4j-2.0.21.jar ScatterBrain` but I got same error :/

Comment: @ErolGuzoğlu Then it's likely you're doing something funky with Args4J; unfortunately I can't dig in to it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason for the problem is I didn't crate any method to use/handle arguments.

Sorry for the silly question.

I wrote "run" method and built at the same command. Code running clearly.

For "run" method look at the below:

```
public void run(){


    if( recursive )
        System.out.println("-r flag is set");


        System.out.println("-str was "+str);

    if( num>=0 )
        System.out.println("-n was "+num);

        // access non-option arguments

        System.out.println("other arguments are:");

    for( String s : arguments )

        System.out.println(s);


}
```